# Excel VBA - Find unique values of none hidden cells

Tags: excel, vba, filter, unique

I have a workbook that I want to apply the filter and then take all of the values of that filter and create them as variables.

I currently have this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CreateUniqueList()

Dim lastrow As Long

ActiveSheet.Name = "Data"

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Data")

Dim uniq As Worksheet
Set uniq = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:= _
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
uniq.Name = "Unique"

ws.Activate

lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

    ActiveSheet.Range("D6:D" & lastrow).AdvancedFilter _
    Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
    CopyToRange:=uniq.Range("A1"), _
    Unique:=True

Dim uniq1 As String
Dim uniq2 As String
Dim uniq3 As String
Dim uniq4 As String


uniq.Activate

uniq1 = Cells(2, 1).Value
uniq2 = Cells(3, 1).Value
uniq3 = Cells(4, 1).Value
uniq4 = Cells(5, 1).Value

End Sub
```

This selects all of the unique values in Worksheet `ws` and pastes them into Worksheet `uniq` in column A. Then the variables are set from there. This works, however I want the user to first filter what values they want in `ws` Column D and then it only to take these unique values.

What happens currently is the user applies the filter, and then runs the macro but it still picks up all the unique values, even then ones not included in the filter.

My question is how can i change this part of the code to not include hidden rows?

```
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

ActiveSheet.Range("D6:D" & lastrow).AdvancedFilter _
Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
CopyToRange:=Champs.Range("A1"), _
Unique:=True
```

Also, if there is any method to clean up the code so I don't need any more lines, that knowledge would be welcome.

Thanks

Comment: I urge you to use an `Array` for the `Champ` variable and assign it using `Champ = Application.Transpose(Worksheets("Unique Champions").Range("A2:A16"))`

Comment: When i  try that I get an error highlighing `Champ = `, saying "Can't assign to array"

Comment: Yes, you should dim it just by `Dim Champ`

Comment: `Dim Champ As String

Champ = Application.Transpose(Worksheets("Unique Champions").Range("A2:A16"))` So now i have this but i get a type mismatch on the second line (`Champ = Application.Transpose(Worksheets("Unique Champions").Range("A2:A16"))`)

Comment: remove `As String`. it will be a `Variant` array but that's better than flattening the code.

Comment: Works, so how do i now call the variables? Champ3 for example doesnt work

Comment: it will be called `Champ(3)` ;)

Comment: I get a syntax error on `;)`. Why dis? I'm kidding, works well and makes the code look much nicer, thanks :)

Comment: Nice one  lol. Well, when you apply the `advanced filter`, the previous `auto-filter` is gone. I will suggest a solution for this, hold on.

Comment: Do you need the sheet `Raw Data`, or is it just a temporary to load the variables?

Comment: I'd like to keep it, could I just copy and paste the data before anything is done to it?

Comment: Ok try my answer below, based on using a dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you apply the advanced filter, the previous auto-filter is gone. So we cannot mix the two filters. However, we can drop the advanced filter and get the unique values using a `Dictionary`.

```
Sub CreateUniqueList()
  Dim dict As Object, lastRow As Long, Champ, c
  Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.dictionary")
  With Sheets("Raw Data")
      lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.count, "D").End(xlUp).row
      For Each c In .Range("D7:D" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        dict(c.text) = 0
      Next
  End With
  Champ = dict.Keys

  ' Now you have the "variables". To create the new sheet:
  With Sheets.Add(After:= Sheets(Sheets.Count))
    .Name = "Unique Champions"
    .Range("A2").Resize(dict.count).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.keys)
    .Range("A1").Value = Sheets("Raw Data").Range("D6").Value
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: If i run exactly what you have above, i get the error '438 - Object doesn't support this property or method'. It highlights line `.Range("A2").Resize(dict.Count).Value = Application.Tranpose(dict.keys)`

Comment: @Dullspark Cant believe how did that letter `s` disappear. It's `Transpose` not `Tranpose` (edited).

Comment: I honestly have no idea how any of that code works but it does so i'm happy enough! Will have to do some research into `Dictionary`. Just to clarify, the array starts at 0. So when I want the variable in cell A2, it's champ(0) right?

Comment: @Dullspark yep, it will be 0-based. Moreover its size will be exactly the number of unique players, not a hard-coded number. Use `LBound(Champ)` and `UBound(Champ)` to reference its boundaries, this is the good way to iterate on arrays, i.e. `For i = LBound(Champ) To UBound(Champ)`

Comment: Sorry to bother you again @A.S.H . I'm trying to call the Champ variable as follows  `If (Cells(i, 2).Value = Champ)` So if that cell contains any of the unique values called in the above code you helped me with, then the IF function would trigger. What would be the syntax to say this?

Comment: @Dullspark Try using matching; this is the best technique to check if something exists in an array: `If Not IsError(Application.Match(Cells(i, 2).Value, Champ,0)) Then`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150305/discussion-between-dullspark-and-a-s-h).

Comment: It returns the Champ value as 0. This is a separate Sub so i put `Public Champ` at the top of everything. That might have something to do with it. I'll post another question on the site and then i can post my code